# Make a listbox menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a simple menu, in the same style as the one in Microsoft Office:

[image: example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [techairlines.com](http://s.techairlines.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/Office-Share.jpg))</sub>

I have tried with a `ListBox` as a menu, but I can't seem to bind each listboxitem to a different panel. Is there an easy way to do this? I would be very grateful if anyone could give some pointers or point me to some tutorials. I feel like I have searched everywhere on the net.

---

I have a few problems. I used Silvermind's code in c# and added an event:

```
    [ContentProperty("Content")]
public class ModelForMyListBox : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    private object content;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            if (value == title)
                return;
            title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
    public object Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set
        {
            if (value == content)
                return;
            content = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In XAML I get an error when I add this.

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Controls"
```

"WpfApplication1.Controls" is not included in the assembly

As for the rest of the XAML I get an error where I use the Controls, but I guess that due to the above error.

Hope you can help me correct the last?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be like this:

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class ModelForMyListBox : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    private object content;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            if (value == title)
                return;
            title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
    public object Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set
        {
            if (value == content)
                return;
            content = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }
}
```

add the namespace of the ModelForMyListBox with a prefix like controls in your window or usercontrol
like `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Application1.Controls"`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="MenuListBox" DisplayMemberPath="Title">
        <controls:ModelForMyListBox Title="Share">
            <!-- <MyCustomViewObject here -->
        </controls:ModelForMyListBox>
        <controls:ModelForMyListBox Title="Help">
            <!-- <MyCustomViewObject here -->
        </controls:ModelForMyListBox>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                      DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MenuListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
                      Content="{Binding Path=Content}"/>
<Grid>
```

I hope this get's you going.

Comment: Thanks alot. Gonna try it out when I get back to my home pc